# constant array separator in excel formula

Tags: excel, vba

What is the seperator list or option to use in constant array to use in a formula excel cell ?

all the Sample [ex: Guidelines in array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-HA010342564.aspx) and help on this show `;` as vertical separator and `,` as horizontal separator. Certainly because i use a localized version for excel from the windows settings (french, dutch and German) it seems that only `;` separator works

```
=MATCH("Apr";{"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May";"Dec"};0)
```

works (giving 4)

```
=VLOOKUP("Apr";{"Jan", "A" ;"Feb", "B";"Apr","D"};2;TRUE)
```

does not accept the `,` syntax (*The formula you type contains an error*) and blink on `"Jan",`

I also try `/` see on some forum post and a space char between the quoted string but with same result.
Is there an option to specify in excel or alterantive for this separator list ?

Comment: Also see: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/separators-for-vertical-and-horizontal-arrays-in-non-english-language-versions-of-excel.1004735/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For French regional settings, you would use \ (not /):

```
=VLOOKUP("Apr"; {"Jan"\"A";"Feb"\"B";"Apr"\"D"}; 2; TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks, it works for this regional settings (by the way, the last `TRUE` is wrong and should be `FALSE` to find due to non sorted value in my sample).

Comment: where can i found that this is `\` ?